# ocaml process ID

Tags: ocaml

How ocaml can raise signal (to be handled via Lwt_unix.on_signal) on the current process that the ocaml is running inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want your program to send a signal to itself. What about this, using the [Unix](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) module?

```
let signal_to_itself number = Unix.kill (Unix.getpid ()) number
```

There are a list of signal numbers at the [Sys](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Sys.html) module, so you could use the function like this:

```
signal_to_itself Sys.sigfpe
```

If you didn't install a handler with Lwt_unix.on_signal, the program will terminate with this:

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```